# cannot display image from link with widget

Tags: java, android, widget

I have a activity widget there's a image view in it.
I tried to import a picture inside it through a link , and i tested everything. The link doesn't have a problem.
The code is good and has no problems.
The problem doesn't show a picture inside Image View.
I need the right adjustments to show the picture from the link. There are no errors in the code.

```
// class widget :

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {



    Context context;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    RemoteViews remoteViews;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        new  DownloadImageTask(remoteViews).execute("https://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg");

        pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
    }

    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews rv) {
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, rv);
    }


    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        RemoteViews bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(RemoteViews bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;

            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                URL newurl = new URL(urldisplay);
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());

                mIcon11 = Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(urldisplay).submit(200, 100).get();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.iv_news_image, bitmap);
        }
    }
}


//xml  widget 
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/widget_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/myshape">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_news_image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        />

</LinearLayout>

// Manifest 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ahmedco.widget_2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>

//  dependencies

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // Glide v4 uses this new annotation processor -- see https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html
    //  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    // Image Loading and Caching
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'





}
```

Comment: maybe (sorry, can't test my suggestion) you should call `pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);` in `onPostExecute()` after you set the correct image resource to the ImageVIew in the Widget? Because right now, you first call  `pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);` then the download starts and then when the image is available you don't update the widget anymore.